# Check if a file is in a html upload form?

Tags: php, file

Okay I can't find a good answer to this, how do i check if a file is actually put into a file upload html form with php?

Doing

```
if (isset($_FILES['new_image']))
```

Always returns that it's set so that's no good. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

All you need is the code below:

```
if(isset($_FILES['new_image'])) {
    // code to execute
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
if(isset($_FILES['new_image']) && $_FILES['new_image']['size'] > 0) {
    // code to execute
}
```

...and your form tag should include at least

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

Comment: This will always be true if the field exists, because `$_FILES['new_image']` is always set.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add and && $_FILES['new_image']['name'] != ''

Comment: And you might also wan't to check so no error occured: `if($_FILES['new_image']['error'] == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

In php you can check if a string is a image or not with GD's [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

This function returns `false` if the image isn't supported, so you can check if the image is valid also.